# Why does this character replacement program not work?

Tags: c, replace, int

The following program compiles but has gibberish data inside of it and doesn't replace..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
    {
    int i;
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a string");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    for (i=0; i<strlen(string);i++)
    {
        if (string[i]=='o')
        {
            string[i]='0';

        }

    }
    printf("%c", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, it would be good if you could explain what 'gibberish data' would be. For instance, a sample session (showing some input, expected output and actual output) would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate strlen before loop

Use %s instead of %c

```
printf("%s", string);
```

As suggested by Vallabh Patade you don't need to calculate length:

```
char *p, string[100];

printf("Enter a string");
p = fgets(string, 100, stdin);
while (*p) {
    if (*p == 'o') *p = '0';
    p++;
}
printf("%s", string);
```

Comment: Why does calculating the length is needed.? Can you please explain.?

Comment: He is calling strlen for each iteration, but obviously while (*string) is a better option

Comment: Would the compiler not optimise this, surely it wouldn't be called each iteration?

Comment: Yeah that's the performance perspective change. right? Or it has impact on desired output.?

Answer (score 1):

1) Change

```
printf("%c", string);
```

to

```
printf("%c", string[i]);
```

inside the loop OR

2) Remove it from loop & add

```
printf("%s", string);
```

After the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing if there is any other problem.  Only the statement should be changed to

```
 printf("%s", string);
```

as we are printing a string. Maybe strings hold desired output just we are printing it in wrong way.